# Define RAM disk size of a custom built kali iso when booted live

Tags: kali-linux, live-usb, livecd, ramdisk

I'm building a custom kali iso and would like to define the size of the root / (tmpfs) partition when it's booted live from an USB. Is this possible?
I've got 32G of ram, and the ram disk size is 50%=16G, so I need to create a new ram disk everytime I boot the read-only USB containing the custom kali ISO